# Excel: How to find Partial matches using the first few characters

Tags: excel

I've been trying to figure this out but I can't:

I'm trying to highlight the duplicate users, between two columns. However, the information isn't exactly the same, the only thing that is the same is that the first few numbers of the user IDs is the same between the two columns.

So how do I find a partial match using the first 7 numbers of the user ID?

Answer (score 0):

You might use conditional formatting, based on a formula.
I don't know the complete formula to perform this, but here's a starting point:

I have created an Excel sheet, containing some entries in column "A".
In column "B", I have entered this formula: `=LEFT(A1,7)`
In column "C", I have entered this formula: `=COUNTIF(B$1:B$5,"="&B1)>1`

Meaning:

- LEFT(A1,7) takes the first seven characters of a string

  - B$1:B$5 : use fixed range: in case you drag down, this does not change
  - B1 (inside that same formula): use relative range: in case you drag down, this does change
- COUNTIF(..., "="&B1): count the amount of times you find "B1".
- `>1`: conditional formatting is based on boolean functions:
  if you have more than one entry, you have duplicates.